# Suppose the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ has the property $a_{n+6} = a_{n}$ for all n ≥ 0.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Suppose the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ has the property $a_{n+6} = a_{n}$ for all n ≥ 0.

1.) Find a formula or a function that equals our series over its interval of convergence.

2.) Find the interval of convergence of the series.

Hint: Write the series as the sum of 6 different series (the first 6 $a_{n}$'s represent ALL constants!), then use algebra to factor out a common (familiar) series.

Comment: To start, I'm having trouble figuring out how to represent the series as the sum of 6 different series.

Answer (score 3):

Say $$ \sum = a_0+a_1x+... = (a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+a_5x^5)(1+x^6+x^{12}+...) = p(x)\cdot {1\over 1-x^6}$$
where $|x^6|<1$. So $x\in(-1,1)$.

Comment: Who would care about p being undefined?

Comment: But $p(x)$ is polynomial and it is alwasy defined. Or not?

Comment: No, p was not defined.  It pop up out of nowhere.

Comment: I really don't now what are you talking about $$p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+a_4x^4+a_5x^5 $$